# How to determine if a class which is an implemenation of an interface in java

Tags: java, class, interface

I need to write a function to return true if the incoming java Class is an implementation of the interface List. Does anybody know how to do this in java?

something like:

```
public boolean canConvert(Class c) {

  //return true is c is an implementation of the interface List

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Kind of odd question. It seems to me that you are having an instance inheriting java.lang.Class implementing a List interface? That doesn't make sense to me. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two distinct scenarios:

- you want to check if a given *class* is a subclass/implementor of `List`. Judging from your method signature (`Class c`), this is what you want. In that case use

  ```
  List.class.isAssignableFrom(c)
  ```
- you want to see if a given object is an instance of a class that us a subclass/implementor of `List`. In that case use `obj instanceof List`, as Bala R suggested.

Answer (score 4):

try using the `instanceof` operator.

```
return c instanceof List;
```

Comment: If c is a class, you want c.isInstance(List.class)

Comment: @bmargulies @Reverend The question says `if c is an implementation of`. we don't know if it's `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: it may indeed be a wrong statement of the question, but I assumed `Class` in the method signature is `java.lang.Class`

Comment: @bmargulies on one hand yes (hence my answer), but the comment inside the method makes it confusing.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an instance the you do

```
c instanceof List
```

if its a class then you do

```
List.class.isAssignableFrom(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling [this function](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) of `Class` which answers the question fairly broadly. If you need to specifically know if it directly implements, you have to walk the data structures.

A more specific answer comes from searching the results of [getInterfaces](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29).